# Why is Ubuntu 16.04 so slow to boot on my Dell Inspiron 6000?

Tags: boot, 16.04

Ubuntu takes roughly 3.5 to 4 minutes to boot on my old Dell Inspiron 6000 (2GB Ram).

Removing powerd solved the problem for someone else's device, but powerd is not loaded on my installation.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 16.04 comes with `systemd` as the start-up manager.

The following command can show you all the startup services of your system from longest to shortest to help you determine what can be causing your slow boot:

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

Here is an example output of that command:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ systemd-analyze blame
          5.077s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
          3.921s postfix.service
          1.806s winbind.service
          1.789s nmbd.service
          1.540s samba-ad-dc.service
          1.405s dev-sde1.device
          1.393s fail2ban.service
          1.222s upower.service
          1.210s accounts-daemon.service
          1.169s vmware.service
          1.034s smbd.service
           895ms apt-daily.service
           797ms media-500GB.mount
           768ms media-250GB_SHARE.mount
           762ms ModemManager.service
           758ms networking.service
           683ms media-Seagate.mount
           639ms NetworkManager.service
           592ms vboxdrv.service
           578ms media-320GB.mount
           453ms grub-common.service
           450ms gpu-manager.service
           420ms vmware-USBArbitrator.service
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Why so slow?**

Ubuntu is a heavy operating system with a lot of demanding resources. It has a lot of "eye-candy" that can slow down the system, too.

**Try a different Ubuntu flavor**

Other Ubuntu flavors, like [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org) or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net), keep all of the features in Ubuntu but with a lighter and faster interface.